# Radio-control over dozens of kilometers and mountains

Tags: radio-control

I am wondering what technology should I use to transmit data (enough for controlling the robot and receiving video) over dozens of kilometers and mountains ?

Answer (score 2):

How far is it in kilometers? What radio frequency you can use? Do you need security (code the data)?

It strongly depends on your application, it seems you need a real-time connection (to control a robot).

In practice you can use an infrastructure such as telephony systems, GPRS or if you have enough resources you can use satellite solutions.

Another solution is to make a network or repeater of [ZigBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee) modules.

Comment: I was in fact thinking about transmission using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_low_frequency since my original question, the project evolved, and now it might be a boat/robot on the sea, so there might be thousands of kilometers of distance, that's why using ionosphere reflexion seems to me a good idea, what do you think about that ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise It would help if you edited this information on your robot into the original question so that people don;t have to wade through the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use high power(1W) radio modems such as [digi XTend](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-modems-peripherals/wireless-range-extenders-peripherals/xtend) or [RFD900](http://store.jdrones.com/jD_RD900_Telemetry_Bindle_p/rf900set01.htm) for controlling your robot. For video transmission you can use high power [analog video](http://www.readymaderc.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=11_30_38&products_id=917) modules. Using proper directional antennas such as [patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_antenna) antennas or [helical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helical_antenna) antennas, you can easily go up to 20+ km in line of site.

Comment: I was in fact thinking about transmission using en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_low_frequency since my original question, the project evolved, and now it might be a boat/robot on the sea, so there might be thousands of kilometers of distance, that's why using ionosphere reflexion seems to me a good idea, what do you think about that ?

Answer (score 0):

You're posting somewhat of a contradiction.  If you want a radio signal with enough bandwidth to transmit video, then you'll have to use [line-of-sight communications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_high_frequency#Line-of-sight_calculation).

To do what you're asking, you'd need more of a network solution, or a very high vantage point (i.e. somewhere in the atmosphere) for your control antenna.

Comment: I am now thinking about ionosphere transmission...

Comment: For what frequencies?  VHF does not reflect off the ionosphere.